# How do I exclude a js file from React transpile?

Tags: reactjs, opencv

I'm working on a React project and one of my components is importing opencv.js. But this is a large file and starting the build will return an error

`JavaScript heap out of memory`

I can increase the memory allocation limit, but now the build doesn't seem to end. It has been running for over an hour.

Is there a way to exclude this file from the transpile? Or is there a better way to include opencv in my project?

`var cv = require('../../src/opencv.js');`

Thanks

I've tried importing opencv.js in various ways, but each runs into the same issue.

I've also tried deleting the opencv.js file during the start function of package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react start && del src/opencv.js"
}
```